# call other scripts from myscript.js

Tags: javascript

Now I have in html file these two scripts. Is possibility to have it only `myscript.js`.
And in `myscript.js` I will have link to `jquery-2.0.3.js`. Is this possible? Or how can I call other scripts from my?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="myscript.js"></script>
```

Comment: You will be better off using something like http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, look into http://requirejs.org/

An example would be something like:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'js/lib',
    paths: {
        jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0'
    }
});
```

They have a really good documentation there too